# Filled a Pojo from XML now to be Inserted into Database

Tags: java, xml, database, persistence

I have 4 classes something like following

```
    Class CollegeRecord{
        List<Student> student;
    }

    Class Student{
       String name;
       List<Books> books;
    }

    Class Books{
       String title;
       List<Authors> authors;
    }

    Class Authors{
      String fName;
      String lName;
}
```

I have got all **POJO's filled** from an XML.  Now i need to Insert it in **Database**.

For which i have to **Loop on Lists** every time Which is not Good

so **Any Other Way? or API?** that can **Persist data into Database without Looping**??

Comment: are you trying to avoid sending a bunch of queries to the db?

Comment: Not Exactly..
I am Actually trying to Avoid the Loops from which i have to take values 1 by 1 and preparing a Query and inserting them in DB.

Comment: What are you using for your persistence? Hibernate? If so then Hibernate will batch them up before saving to DB.

Comment: Someone suggested me to go for Hibernate..
But i don't want to do it just for these 3 DB tables.
Bcz Entire Application is Running on simple Queries.